# WPF DataGrid EnableColumnVirtualization="True" Raises NullReferenceException at DataGridCellsPanel.get_HasCorrectRealizedColumns()

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I have a WPF DataGrid with`EnableColumnVirtualization="True"`. The user control displays but as soon as you scroll or resize you'll receive a `NullReferenceException` at `DataGridCellsPanel.get_HasCorrectRealizedColumns()`. Setting `ColumnVirtualization="False"` corrects the issue. I've tried removing `EnableRowVirtualization="True"` ... etc thinking that maybe it was due to a combination of properties but I'm able to reproduce the issue with a very simple DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
```

Has anyone else run into this? I'm running Win7 64. Thanks all!

```
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.get_HasCorrectRealizedColumns()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter.SyncProperties(Boolean forcePrepareCells)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.SyncProperties(Boolean forcePrepareCells)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.PrepareRow(Object item, DataGrid owningDataGrid)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.InsertContainer(Int32 childIndex, UIElement container, Boolean isRecycled)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.AddContainerFromGenerator(Int32 childIndex, UIElement child, Boolean newlyRealized, Boolean isBeforeViewport)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator& generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider, IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem, Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Boolean& computedAreContainersUniformlySized, IList& items, Object& item, IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport, VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit& cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double& firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size& stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize, Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean& mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure, Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean& hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean& hasVirtualizingChildren)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Boolean remeasure)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InitializeViewport>b__7()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ....App.Main() in c:\....\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
```

Comment: try adding CanUserAddRow="False"

Comment: Tried that but still received the exception. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get to it going by changing the `VirtualizationMode` from Recycling to Standard.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="True"
     EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
     Standard.VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
     VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
```

I'd still like to know why Recycling doesn't work ... bug?

Hope this helps anyone that runs into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Examining the events stack using Snoop you can see that each row is 'wrapped' in a SelectiveScrollingGrid control. When you scroll, a Rectangle in that control receives MouseDown event that bubbles up to something else. In my case, the something else is an Expander with a command/action attached. This gets fired and changes the underlying list. Is it the underlying list being rewritten that causes the error or simply the firing of the event? Whatever, your solution works.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight. It all helps.

Comment: Setting VirtualizationMode to Standard isn't viable if you're showing grids with a lot of data (a lot of columns). It slows down the control performance significantly. We keep having such issues with WPF's UI Virtualization all the time.