# WPF DataGrid Loading very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a **WPF Application** which contains a **DataGrid**. The DataGrid contains 10 DataGridTemplateColumns. I add 4 additonal DataGridTemplateColumns to it,but after that ththe DataGrid loads very slowly. I use **List** as its **ItemSource**. Please help me to solve the issue.

This is my DataGrid XAML

```
<DataGrid   VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"  
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            BorderBrush="Transparent" 
            ClipToBounds="True" 
            GridLinesVisibility="All"  
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            HeadersVisibility="Column"  
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600"
            Name="gvGrid" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.RowSpan="7"  
            CanUserDeleteRows="True"  
            CanUserAddRows="False"  
            CanUserResizeColumns="False"   
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
            CanUserResizeRows="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridContentCellCentering}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="200" 
            ColumnWidth="*"   
            EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#E7E5E6" 
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="#E7E5E6"
            ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" 
            AlternatingRowBackground="#F6F4F5" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            Background="{x:Null}" 
            CurrentCellChanged="gvGrid_CurrentCellChanged">
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of precautions you can consider for improving your `DataGrid`'s performance.

First of all use virtualization (just set properties `EnableColumnVirtualization` and `EnableRowVirtualization` to `true` and avoid to put your `DataGrid` in a `ScrollViewer`, since it nullifies virtualization's benefits). Second step, use an async binding for the `ItemsSource` property, i.e.:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourList, IsAsync=True}"
```

They should help you.

Comment: EnableColumnVirtualization  shows Null Reference Exception

Comment: @ArjunPV, please, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098908/wpf-datagrid-enablecolumnvirtualization-true-raises-nullreferenceexception-at)